# How to group similar items in a list using C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I been trying to tackle this for half a day now, with no luck. I have a bunch of objects in a list. I want to sort the list by equal y values, which I did here:

```
ListOfObjects.Sort((y1,y2) => y1.y.CompareTo(y2.y));
```

But now I want to separate all objects with equal y values in new lists. How would I approach this?

Comment: could you provide an example input/output?

Comment: Alright sure, will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
var groups = ListOfObjects.GroupBy(x => x.y);
```

And if you explicitly want lists:

```
var lists = ListOfObjects.GroupBy(x => x.y).Select(x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: I'm tinkering around with this right so give me a moment.

Comment: I think I'll come back later with a more detailed question, I just have to write a basic outline of my problem, but thank you for your help. I'll mark this as right as it does answer my base question.